# Write to a file to bypass memory cap when generating a big variable. Python 3.3

Tags: python, windows

I don't know how advanced this will be but, I am trying to generate a huge list of permutations and then parse them to print them in a specific way. THe problem I'm having is that when I use the following line:
`x=([''.join(i) for i in itertools.product("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890",repeat=8)])`

I run into the problem that my computer is either 32 bit or has only 4 gigs of RAM. So I am wondering if there is a way to stop this line halfway through, write all the ones generated to a txt file, then continue. The idea is that that way the variable is stored on the disk instead of in the RAM. I will then parse the txt file later to get the situation I am looking for. I'm on Windows 7 by the way.
Thanks!

Comment: There are more than 218 trillion of these things:  you don't have enough disk space to write out more than a fraction of them.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It sounds like you're brute-forcing a problem that would be solved better a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just break it down into its components and save as you go.  Something like:

```
for i in itertools.product(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, repeat=8):
     print(''.join(i))
```

Comment: This worked great, and I could see the texts as they were being generated. I don't know how I overlooked just using a for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First thing to note:

```
>>> len("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890") ** 8
218340105584896L
>>> format(_, ",")
'218,340,105,584,896'
```

That's how many products there are.  Written out, each would take 8 bytes plus a newline character (or other delimiter).

```
>>> 62 ** 8 * 9
1965060950264064L
```

So if you buy about 2,000 1-terabyte disks, you'll have just enough disk space to store them all.

Still want to go down this path? ;-)  Once you buy all that hardware:

```
import itertools
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
with open("perms.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in itertools.product(s, repeat=8):
        f.write("".join(i) + "\n")
```

will do it using very little RAM.

Comment: I don't know what it was, bu the program would run forever and notepad would crash when I tried to pen the document. The guy with the solution below, gives me instant results, and that's what I like. Thanks for the explanation though!

Comment: Think!  There are trillions and trillions and trillions of results.  You don't have enough RAM or disk space to store more than a tiny fraction of all of them.  Nobody does, except maybe for the NSA ;-)  We'll all be dead long before any program to generate all the results finishes.  The two solutions you were given are identical, except that the one I gave you prints to a file and the other one prints to standard output.  Neither of them will finish in your lifetime.